# OpenLayers: disable zooming on double-click

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

OpenLayers, by default, zooms in when a user double clicks a map.

What is the best way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *zoom on double click* feature is apparently a functionality in the `OpenLayers.Control.Navigation` control. See the [*OpenLayers Reference*](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/Navigation-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.Navigation.defaultDblClick) for more information.

A small and very tired example:

```
var Navigation = new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
    defaultDblClick: function(event) { return; }
});
```

I remember that the *Navigation* control is automatically added to the map if no controls are set during the initialization of the map. So you might have to add the Navigation control your self.

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Note that you apply this to the map like so `map.addControl(Navigation);`

Answer (score 11):

OpenLayers 3 Documentation [Link](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.html#defaults).

Static way:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ doubleClickZoom: false }),
    ...
});
```

Dynamic way:

```
var interactions = map.getInteractions();
for (var i = 0; i < interactions.getLength(); i++) {
    var interaction = interactions.item(i);                          
    if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom) {
        map.removeInteraction(interaction);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. Thank you +1

Answer (score 7):

The above answer is correct, but you will have to explicitly add this control to the map to override the default Navigation control, ie,

```
var Navigation = new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
  defaultDblClick: function(event) { return; }
});

map.addControl(Navigation);
```

The following controls are added by default to an OpenLayers.Map:
OpenLayers.Control.Navigation,
OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom,
OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser,
OpenLayers.Control.Attribution

So another option if you want to turn all these default behaviors off, is to send an empty array in the options parameter of the open layers map constructor, see [link text](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js) for more details.

Comment: What does not work: changing the defaultDblClick method on the map's navigation control instance.